# In Javascript, the value 0/0 returns NaN. But why does the typeof operator return this value as a Number type?

Tags: javascript, numbers, nan

In Javascript, the value 0/0 returns NaN. But why does the typeof operator return this value as a Number type? I was expecting typeof to also return NaN.

```
let value = 0/0
console.log(value, typeof(value))
```

The console returns: NaN, "Number"

Comment: Because you expect an arithmetic operation to return a number right? It would be fun if an operator would return different types depending on the value of the operands.

Answer (score 2):

Because NAN is a number!! lol gotta love JS!

```
typeof(NaN)
//= number
```

A good description from: https://javascriptrefined.io/nan-and-typeof-36cd6e2a4e43

> The ECMAScript standard states that Numbers should be IEEE-754 floating point data. This includes Infinity, -Infinity, and also NaN.

By definition, NaN is the return value from operations which have an undefined numerical result. Hence why, in JavaScript, aside from being part of the global object, it is also part of the Number object: Number.NaN. It is still a numeric data type, but it is undefined as a real number.